# Broadcast server end messages to clients using Websockets

Tags: go

I am new to Golang, I am trying to a create a WebSocket server which will broadcast messages to the connected clients. The messages here will be generated from the server side(by creating a default client).

Here is my client.go

```
c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dial:", err)
}
defer c.Close()
done := make(chan struct{})
new_chan := make(chan string)
//defer new_chan.Stop()
go func() {
    for {
        new_chan <- "my message"
    }
}()

hub := newHub()
go hub.run()
client := &Client{hub: hub, ws: c, send: make(chan []byte, 256)}

for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case t := <-new_chan:
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            return
        }
        log.Printf(t)
        client.hub.broadcast <- bytes.TrimSpace(bytes.Replace([]byte(t), newline, space, -1))
    }
}
```

this function will generate the messages and try to broadcast to other clients.

server.go will add the clients to the hub

```
func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("upgrade:", err)
    return
}
hub := newHub()
go hub.run()

client := &Client{hub: hub, ws: c, send: make(chan []byte, 256)}
client.hub.register <- client

go client.writePump()
```

writePump() here will listen to the client.send channel and broadcast messages
Now the connected client's hub is different is from the hub of the client at the server. So when I try to send messages, I am not receiving anything.
How can I make it belong to the same hub(context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are starting from the [Gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat). In that example, use `hub.broadcast <- message` to broadcast a message to all clients where `hub` is the `*Hub` created in `main()`.

There's no need to create a client connection to send message originated from the server.

Here's a modified version of the main() that broadcasts "hello" to all clients every second:

```
func broadcast(hub *Hub) {
    m := []byte("hello")
    for range time.NewTicker(time.Second).C {
        hub.broadcast <- m
    }
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    hub := newHub()
    go hub.run()
    go broadcast(hub)
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveHome)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        serveWs(hub, w, r)
    })
    err := http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```